# Handling Django/Postgres Natural Foreign Key Cascading Updates

Tags: python, django, postgresql, triggers

In my application and database, I have `Compound` and `Name` models.

```
# possible names of compound
class Name(models.Model):
    compound_name = models.TextField(primary_key=True)

# compound
class Compound(models.Model):
    # unique id for the compound
    compound_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # name representing the compound
    primary_name = models.ForeignKey(Name, db_column='compound_name', null=True,  db_index=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

What I'd like to have happen is when I change a name, say 'apsirin' to 'aspirin', this change would cascade to my Compound.

Currently, because of the way Django handles these FK relationships, this doesn't work. If I update a name entry in django, it actually just creates a new entry, and the old compound retains the linkage to the compound.

I've thought of 3 possible solutions, but I'm not quite sure what all the drawbacks are of each.

1. make a custom 'update' function for my names, that first gets/creates the new name entry, finds all the compounds/other link tables with references to the old name, and then replaces all of the old name values with the new name values, before finally deleting the old name. Possible drawback is that I don't know how this would work if someone was using django admin to update names.
2. Use signals to intercept an update before it attempted to make the update in the database, and perform something similar to (1)
3. Create a trigger in postgres to perform something similar to (1) before updates occur. I'm not quite sure if Django would throw an error on this though, since it would be unaware of the trigger.

Its possible I'm just overlooking some basic functionality of models in models.py, and if I am, then hopefully that can solve this issue. But I don't see any kinds of `on_update` params for the FKs, and I've read that the Django team has labelled this a 'wont fix' issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it yet but:

FK is FK, we just care about FK_id to link it (1)

You can change name of the models and makemigrations (2)

```
# in SQL, i saw it create model_old, then create a new model and copy (for the function about add and remove field)
# in makemigrations, when change name: it just run the Update query.
```

When change name, nothing happen to data, it just update the name (3)

When you change the name of a FK (it still just change the name again) (4)

From (1), we can access the data of FK ~> Nothing about change name or something like this can make problem.

So:

Just make sure you create a good models.

To logic should start from model, and fit with your idea.